# Can't get `align-items="baseline"` to work

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, react-typescript

I can duplicate the problem on the linked sandbox project but basically I want the bottom of texts (different font sizes) to be lined up/on the same y axis. Not sure how else to put it.

Look at this pic to see what I need. Code below. What am I missing?

[ExpectationVsReality.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIKwD.png)

[Sandbox project](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-wave-bymf4?file=/src/App.tsx:0-334)

```
import "@material-ui/core";
import { Box } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Box display="flex" align-items="baseline" flex-direction="row">
        <Box fontSize="2em" fontWeight="600">
          Belinda Carlisle
        </Box>
        <Box>12345678</Box>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a style of `align-self: flex-end;` to the elements you want to have positioned at the bottom, in your case, if you want all of your elements to be bottom aligned, it would look something like:

```
.MuiBox-root {
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

In the case you want some just some element to behave like this, make a new class with the same style:

```
.aligned-bottom {
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

**Edited:**
On your `App.tsx` file, add the stylesheet too:

```
import "./styles.css";
```

[Add stylesheet to your project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvHCR.png)

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference. I placed it on each of the elements as well as the parent element and nothing happens.

Comment: on your `App.tsx` you also have to add the stylesheet, like: `import "./styles.css";`

Answer (score 0):

Had the name of the field wrong: `alignItems="baseline"`